# how to create dynamic proxy with java condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dynamic, proxy

I need your help.
I have a Spring annotation that I apply to an interface. This interface is implemented by another class. I need to create a proxy object for classes that implement the interface with my annotation. This proxy object should have two implementations:

- the first one with the original logic
- the second one without any logic, just as a placeholder.

Additionally, this should be wrapped in an `if()` conditional statement. If you have any ideas or suggestions, I would be grateful.

I tried to create a proxy object and disable and display, but for some reason they do not fall into the context

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have situation like this:

```java
public interface MyService {
    void doSomething();
}

@CustomProxy
public class OriginalService implements MyService {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // Original logic here
    }
}

public class PlaceholderService implements MyService {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // No logic or placeholder logic here
    }
}
```

I would try to use Spring AOP like so:

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Aspect
@Configuration
public class ProxyAspect {

    @Before("@within(com.example.CustomProxy)")
    public void beforeCustomProxy() {
        // Logic to determine which version of the proxy to use
        // You can conditionally switch between OriginalService and PlaceholderService
        boolean condition = /* your condition here */;

        if (condition) {
            // Return the instance of OriginalService
        } else {
            // Return the instance of PlaceholderService
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this has been helpful to you